# Getting "Expected private key to be an Uint8Array with length 32" when running a transfer function on ropsten testnet through my terminal

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs, ethers.js, ethereumjs

i am trying to send a transaction but it throws an error.

**MY CODE:**

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/3612545f6ba447f2a3f24543cf915744')

const account1 = '0x414c87f17fa2071C2Ed6583839609ae116B5C1E9'
const account2 = '0x8bbaf0933C14e2d5Cec5D7cB1A0C06c512F7F05A'

const privateKey1 = Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1)
const privateKey2 = Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_2)

const contractABI = //had to remove to shorten the code,
contractAddress = '0x27A9d446A882D92E29cab27F7Ce3C9f8ec578e94'

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress)

const data = contract.methods.transfer(account2, 1000).encodeABI()


web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {

    // Create transaction object
    const txObject = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(800000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
    to: contractAddress,
    data: data
    }

    // Sign the transaction
    const tx = new Tx(txObject,{ chain: 'ropsten' })
    tx.sign( privateKey1 )

    const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

    // Broadcast the transaction
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
        console.log('err:', err, 'txHash', txHash)
    //Use this txHash to get the cotract on etherscan
   })

})
```

**ERROR ON NODE TERMINAL:**

```
if (!cond) throw new Error(msg)
             ^

Error: Expected private key to be an Uint8Array with length 32
    at assert (/Users/B money/node_modules/secp256k1/lib/index.js:18:20)
    at isUint8Array (/Users/B money/node_modules/secp256k1/lib/index.js:31:7)
    at Object.ecdsaSign (/Users/B money/node_modules/secp256k1/lib/index.js:254:7)
    at Object.exports.sign (/Users/B money/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/secp256k1v3-adapter.js:247:25)
    at Object.exports.ecsign (/Users/B money/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/signature.js:12:25)
    at Transaction.sign (/Users/B money/node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/dist/transaction.js:230:37)
    at /Users/B money/app.js:32:5
    at Object._fireError (/Users/B money/node_modules/web3-utils/lib/index.js:52:9)
    at sendTxCallback (/Users/B money/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:548:30)
    at /Users/B money/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:297:20
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/B money/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/B money/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/B money/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/Users/B money/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:349:14)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/B money/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:252:61)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
```

Comment: Could you please make this more minimal? This is a "could you debug my code" question, not a specific one. Thank you.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean.  I am new to the platform so I don't really understand what you mean by that.